# main method won't run while loop in java

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop, blackjack

Hello I am writing a file in java that allows the user to play blackjack against the computer. Below is my code. Whenever i run it inside Dr.javait says running main method however nothing happens. I know if you don't give a while a loop a condition to end it is infinite however I believe I have given an end condition in my code but I could be mistaken.

```
public class BlackJack {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean playing = true;
        Random card = new Random();
        int playerCard1 = card.nextInt(11)+1;
        int playerCard2= card.nextInt(10)+1;
        int dealerCard1= card.nextInt(11)+1;
        int dealerCard2= card.nextInt(11)+1;
        int playerTotal= playerCard1 + playerCard2;
        boolean bust = true;
        boolean blackJack = true;
        while(playing) { // start while loop, loop until playing is false
            while((!blackJack) || (!bust)){ // begin while loop
                System.out.println("You drew a:" + playerCard1 + " and a " + playerCard2);
                System.out.println("Your total is:" + playerTotal);
                System.out.println("The dealer has a: " + dealerCard1 + "showing and a hidden card");
                if(playerTotal ==21) {
                    System.out.println("Your total is: " + playerTotal);
                    System.out.println("BLACKJACK! You WON!");
                    blackJack = true;
                    playing = false;
                }
                while (playerTotal <21){ // begin while loop
                    String playerDecision=in.next();
                    if(playerDecision.equals( "hit")) { // if player hits
                        int playerCard = card.nextInt(11)+1;
                        playerTotal = playerCard1 + playerCard2 + playerCard;
                        System.out.println("You drew a: " + playerCard);
                        System.out.println("Your total is now:" + playerTotal);
                    } else if (playerDecision.equals("Stay")) {
                        // player decides to stay 
                        System.out.println("Okay! It is now the dealer's turn");
                        System.out.println("His hidden card was:" + dealerCard2);
                        int dealerTotal = dealerCard1 + dealerCard2;
                        System.out.println("His total was: " + dealerTotal);
                        if(dealerTotal == 21) {
                            blackJack = true;
                            System.out.println("The dealer won");
                        } 
                        while (dealerTotal < 16) { // begin while for dealerTotal <16 
                            int dealerCard = card.nextInt(11)+1;
                            System.out.print("The dealer chose to hit");
                            System.out.println("He drew a:" + dealerCard);
                            dealerTotal = dealerCard1 + dealerCard2 + dealerCard;
                            System.out.println("His is total is: " + dealerTotal);
                        } // end while
                        if(dealerTotal >21) { // if dealer goes over 21 he busts, bust is true
                            System.out.println("The Dealer BUSTS! You WON!" );
                            bust = true;
                            playing = false;
                        } else if(dealerTotal >playerTotal) {
                            System.out.println("The Dealer Won! You lost");
                            blackJack = true;
                            playing= false;
                        } else if(playerTotal > dealerTotal) { 
                            System.out.println("You Won");
                            blackJack = true;
                            playing = false;
                        }
                    } // end else if player stays
                }
            }
        } // end while loop for player<21
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though you are initializing the boolean value of blackjack to be true, but your first while loop only starts if this value is false: *!blackjack*, the simple fix is to change it so that blackjack = false at the class level.

```
...
boolean bust = true;
boolean blackJack = false;

while(playing) { // start while loop, loop until playing is false

    while((!blackJack) || (!bust)){ // begin while loop
...
```

Comment: I changed the value to false but it still won't run

Comment: it says running main method but nothing happens